# PHP: How to pass array as argument to receiving function that uses func_get_args?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with getting an array (with all its data) over to a receiving function. I am passing the array over as a constructor argument ($myarray):

```
$s = new MyQuery($param1, $myarray);
```

The receiving side is a MyQuery object receiving the arguments, using:

```
$a = func_get_args();
```

But it does not give me the values in the array:
If I do:

```php
$size=func_num_args();
$a=func_get_args();
for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) {
    if (is_array($a[$i])){
        $arr = $a[$i]; //trying to get the very array....
        echo ($arr[0]);
    }
}
```

.. the echo here does just say "Array". Does it have to do with the func_get_args() function?
Very thankful for any help.

Comment: The printed string "Array" indicates that $arr[0] is an array itself. Try var_dump($arr[0]); instead to better understand what you're accessing.

Comment: Thank you very much!
var_dump ($a[$i]) gives:
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" } }
Now I am one step further! How to access "cat" directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```php
<?php

function foo()
{
    $argsCount = func_num_args();
    $args=func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $argsCount ; $i++) {
        if (is_array($args[$i])){
            print_r($args[$i]);
        }
    }
}

foo(1, 2, [3]);   
?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
At least, by using var_dump and print_r, I see the array data is actually there. But I cannot use it like that.I must be able to get at that value directly, what is the syntax?
var_dump ($a[$i]) gives: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" } } 
I cant use var_dump in my real app. I want to get "cat" as a value to use.

Comment: try this `$a[$i][0][0]`

Comment: SPLENDIDO!!!!! Great! Thank you very much for help!

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you upvote my answer and choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should be able to get you array with this piece of code

But `echo` can't print the full array.

Try replacing `echo ($arr[0]);` by `var_dump($arr);` or `print_r($arr);`